# What conditional logic to use for numbers with leading zeros?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I am running ColdFusion Enterprise 9.0.1.274733 on Windows Server 2008 R2 with Java 1.6.0_22.

I am calling a SOAP web service that returns various data to me. One of the data elements contains a code consisting of numbers with leading zeros. I am trying to convert that code into a text description but am having problems with the leading zeros. I have tried using the `cfswitch` tag as well as various things with the `cfif` tag.  They are behaving a bit differently. I am looking for some suggestions on how to best handle these codes.

Here is an example of the code to description lookup:

```
Code     Description
 01      Automobile
 010     Personal Automobile
 011     Commercial Automobile
 02      Home
 03      Boat
 10      Life
 11      Umbrella
```

I initially attempted to use a `cfswitch` block to handle this but found that it treats the code as an integer.  So as far as `cfswitch` is concerned; `010` is equal to `10`.  I have also tried using `cfif`.  It also appears to be converting the value during the comparison. So as far as `cfif` is concerned the opposite is true;  `10` is equal to `010`.

How do you guys handle this issue?

Here is some example code that shows what is happening:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <cfset testvals = "01,010,011,10,11,12" />
    <cfoutput>
    <div>
        <cfloop list="#testvals#" index="testval">
            <p>testval = [#testval#]
            <cfswitch expression="#testval#">
                <cfcase value="01">    <cfset desc="matches 01" />    </cfcase>
                <!---<cfcase value="010">    <cfset desc="matches 010" /></cfcase> --->
                <!---<cfcase value="011">    <cfset desc="matches 011" /></cfcase> --->
                <cfcase value="02">    <cfset desc="matches 02" />    </cfcase>
                <cfcase value="03">    <cfset desc="matches 03" />    </cfcase>
                <cfcase value="04">    <cfset desc="matches 04" />    </cfcase>
                <cfcase value="08">    <cfset desc="matches 08" />    </cfcase>
                <cfcase value="09">    <cfset desc="matches 09" />    </cfcase>
                <cfcase value="10">    <cfset desc="matches 10" />    </cfcase>
                <cfcase value="11">    <cfset desc="matches 11" />    </cfcase>
                <cfcase value="12">    <cfset desc="matches 12" />    </cfcase>
                <cfdefaultcase>        <cfset desc="no match" />    </cfdefaultcase>
            </cfswitch>
            <br />cfswitch: #desc#

            <cfif testval EQ "01">
                <cfset desc="matches 01" />
            <cfelseif testval EQ "010">
                <cfset desc="matches 010" />
            <cfelseif testval EQ "011">
                <cfset desc="matches 011" />
            <cfelseif testval EQ "02">
                <cfset desc="matches 02" />
            <cfelseif testval EQ "03">
                <cfset desc="matches 03" />
            <cfelseif testval EQ "04">
                <cfset desc="matches 04" />
            <cfelseif testval EQ "08">
                <cfset desc="matches 08" />
            <cfelseif testval EQ "09">
                <cfset desc="matches 09" />
            <cfelseif testval EQ "10">
                <cfset desc="matches 10" />
            <cfelseif testval EQ "11">
                <cfset desc="matches 11" />
            <cfelseif testval EQ "12">
                <cfset desc="matches 12" />
            <cfelse>
                <cfset desc="no match" />
            </cfif>
            <br />cfif: #desc#

            <cfif toString(testval) EQ "01">
                <cfset desc="matches 01" />
            <cfelseif toString(testval) EQ "010">
                <cfset desc="matches 010" />
            <cfelseif toString(testval) EQ "011">
                <cfset desc="matches 011" />
            <cfelseif toString(testval) EQ "02">
                <cfset desc="matches 02" />
            <cfelseif toString(testval) EQ "03">
                <cfset desc="matches 03" />
            <cfelseif toString(testval) EQ "04">
                <cfset desc="matches 04" />
            <cfelseif toString(testval) EQ "08">
                <cfset desc="matches 08" />
            <cfelseif toString(testval) EQ "09">
                <cfset desc="matches 09" />
            <cfelseif toString(testval) EQ "10">
                <cfset desc="matches 10" />
            <cfelseif toString(testval) EQ "11">
                <cfset desc="matches 11" />
            <cfelseif toString(testval) EQ "12">
                <cfset desc="matches 12" />
            <cfelse>
                <cfset desc="no match" />
            </cfif>
            <br />tostring: #desc#
            </p>
        </cfloop>
    </div>
    </cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I had to comment out the `cfcase` tags for the values of `010` and `011` to avoid an error. If those are in the `cfswitch` then I get this error: `Context validation error for the cfcase tag. The cfswitch tag has a duplicate cfcase tag for value 10.0. The error occurred on line -1.`

Here is the output from the example code:

```
Test

testval = [01] 
cfswitch: matches 01 
    cfif: matches 01 
tostring: matches 01

testval = [010] 
cfswitch: matches 10     // trying to avoid this
    cfif: matches 010 
tostring: matches 010

testval = [011] 
cfswitch: matches 11     // trying to avoid this
    cfif: matches 011 
tostring: matches 011

testval = [10] 
cfswitch: matches 10 
    cfif: matches 010    // trying to avoid this
tostring: matches 010    // trying to avoid this

testval = [11] 
cfswitch: matches 11 
    cfif: matches 011    // trying to avoid this
tostring: matches 011    // trying to avoid this

testval = [12] 
cfswitch: matches 12 
    cfif: matches 12 
tostring: matches 12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often use `compare()` to avoid undesired implicit conversion problems:

```
   <cfif compare("010", testVal) EQ 0>
       matches 010
   </cfif>
```

But if you are just returning a single value, have you considered using a structure to do a simple look-up instead?

```
 <cfset lookup = { "010"="matches 010", ...} > 
 <cfif structKeyExists(lookup, testVal)>
     do something with #lookup[ testVal ]# ...
 </cfif>
```

> So as far as cfswitch is concerned; 010 is equal to 10

**Edit:** That sounds a little buggy IMO. The documentation mentions [a similar issue with `0` versus `00`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fe5.html) and states that it was fixed. But the error still occurs in CF 9. So you may want to submit a bug report.

> The value "00" was also evaluated to the value 0. This caused the
>   exception “Context validation error for tag CFCASE. The CFSWITCH has a
>   duplicate CFCASE for value "0.0".” The  tag now returns the
>   expected result.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Leigh. Using `compare` seems to work. I do not use that function very often so overlooked it. I had not considered using a structure, interesting. On the docs, they also mention this for the `cfswitch` _ColdFusion converts integers, real numbers, Booleans, and dates to numeric values. For example, true, 1, and 1.0 are all equal._  So not sure if it is a bug or working as designed. I was not expecting it to work this way.

Comment: True, but that also contradicts the history section which claims `0` and `00` are treated differently. So there is a bug - whether it is in the documentation or behavior. I am torn. On the one hand, I am used to languages that only allow numbers in `switch/case`. However, since CF *does* allow strings, my expectation would be that values with leading zeros would treated as a string ie `00010` != `10` . That said, the reason for the behavior is clear. It is just not necessarily what one would expect.

Comment: I think it's working as designed.  It comes under the general theme of "coldfusion is supposed to make things easy so non-programmers can use it".

Comment: @Leigh I am very intrigued by your structure recommendation. I don't typically use structures for something like this but it seems to work nicely as well. Do you have any idea on the performance differences between using a structure versus using cfswitch/cfif tags for something like this?

Comment: @Miguel-F - Honestly, I am not sure. For string comparisons, I am guessing structures would have the edge. But that is just a guess. (Edit) `</boilerplate mention of premature optimization here>` ;)

Comment: Thanks again @Leigh, as usual you have been extremely helpful. I think I am going to use your structure suggestion since these are simple one-to-one string values. Makes the code easier to read too.

Comment: You read my mind :) I was about to say, I would recommend using structures anyway simply for maintainability and readability reasons.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Behaving contrary to general expectations makes things harder, not easier, IMO. But regardless of my opinion, the documentation should accurately describe the *actual* behavior. Right now it seems to contradict itself.

Comment: Ironically we were testing cfswitch/if/struct lookup yesterday based on a different question on SO. Key lookup is wicked fast and can easily be swapped out with ifs, especially with the added effect of being cleaner code (IMO).

Comment: @Busches - thanks for the confirmation. By chance did you test different ways of accessing the structures; `lookup.testval` versus `lookup[testval]` versus `StructFind(lookup,testval)` ? Or do they all perform the same?

Comment: @Miguel-F we did not. Shouldn't be to hard to compare the difference.

Comment: I do not have time to test it, but my guess would be direct access has the edge over `StructFind` :) Though it would probably take a lot of repetitions to be measurable.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use val() and then do the cfswitch??? Val() will strip all leading zeroes from the value:

```
<cfset a = "010">
<cfset b = val(a)>

<cfdump var="#a#">
<cfdump var="#b#">
<cfdump var="#b eq 10#">
```

Comment: I think you misread it. He *wants* to do a string comparison, not numeric :) ie `00010` should not equal `10`.

Comment: Right Leigh. From the service '010' and '10' are different.